# Add a custom layout before the list displayed by the adapter of a ListFragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` that displays a list. All good. I wanted to put some well formatted textview preceding the list.
I tried creating a linear layout with a textview and adding it as a header to the list but it does not work.
The following does work:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
 tv.setText(“Some title with comments”);
 getListView().addHeaderView(tv);
 tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
 tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
```

I get the text before the list but I would like to actually set a layout instead as I would like text with 2 different fonts (it is like a title/caption with big font and a small description with smaller font).
How can I do that?
I don’t have any layout with list view defined. I only have a `ListFragment` and my custom listAdapter

**Update:**
What I also tried and did not work:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_header, container, false);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

And later when setting the adapter:
`getListView().addHeaderView(this.headerView);`
But I got exceptions

Comment: The ListView gets created and setup in super.onCreateView. If you need to do anything with it, do it in onViewCreated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps for properly adding a header in a ListFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View list_root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);
      // Get the list header - to be added later in the lifecycle
      // during onActivityCreated()
      mheaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_header, null);
      return list_root;

    }


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     if (mheaderView != null)  this.getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);
     // Don't forget to now call setListAdapter()
     this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();

    // free adapter
    setListAdapter(null);
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer. The problem is that your code is in onCreateView. I assume that in the onCreate method you inflate the listview, there you should also add your header.

Comment: I am not inflating a listview anywhere. I am using a `ListFragment` and inflating a listitem in my custom adapter

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot you were using ListFragment. So, as you can see, you should add headerView onActivityCreated. Hope this works.

Comment: It works! The difference is that I did `return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` in my `onCreateView` method. What is this `View list_root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);` about?

Comment: That's great! It also works if you inflate your view from a custom layout, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter, inside your `getView()`, you can load your header layout while position is `0`.

Check out my code.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(position==0)
{
 //view 1
}
else
{
Rest of the list elements
}
```

Comment: Load it how? I am new in android

Comment: When I tried to inflate a layout in  `onViewCreate` and keep it as a reference in a variable and then do: `getListView().addHeaderView(this.headerView);` it crashes

Comment: This does not work. I tried:  `if ( position == 0 ) {
                View header = getLayoutInflater(getArguments()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_header, null, false);
                getListView().addHeaderView(header);
                return convertView;
            }`

Comment: Let me know your problem in this case.

Comment: The [`HeaderViewListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html) which is internally used by the `ListView` does this already. Just use `ListView.addHeaderView` and it's taken care of. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @SamirBhatt:The whole list is blank

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom view with the specifics you need, and then then, for the method "addHeaderView" you can assign you view.

eg:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null); 
ListView listView = getListView();  
listView.addHeaderView(header);  
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Comment: This code does not compile. `getLayoutInflater` expects some argument

Comment: `View header = LayoutInflater.from(getView().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, getListView(), false)`

Answer (score 1):

Write an ArrayAdapter extending ArrayAdapter
then do this inside getView method...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Contact contact = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, parent, false);
    }
//Do whatever u need to do with that View...
    return convertView
}
```